# Nothing happens when trying menu toggle using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am only new to the whole javascript/jQuery world and am having some issues that I am not able to identify. I am testing the .toggle with a list which will be a menu. However, when I press the temporary button I have in place for the menu to toggle, nothing happens.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuIcon").click(function() {
    $("#menu").fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#menuIcon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #menuIcon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="menuIcon">Click Me</button>
<div id="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Page</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine you just have to add the ***jquery cdn script***.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #menuIcon{
        display: none;
    }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            #menu{

                display: none;
            }
            #menuIcon{
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="menuIcon">Click Me</button>
    <div id="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Page</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#menuIcon").click(function(){
                $("#menu").fadeIn(1000);
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something simple. Appreciate it!

Comment: wish I had seen that **before** editing the question into a code snippet... (Because it works in the snippet)

Comment: Thanks you... Mark the answer .. so that others dont have to repost here anymore and question is closed :)

Comment: @CarlO'Beirne check the answer with jquery menu toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Link the jquery script in the code and use Jquery **toggle**, to toggle your `display` for menu.

```
$("#menu").toggle("display")
```

Currently you are just fading in the menu.

Check the below **updated** code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #menuIcon{
        display: none;
    }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            #menu{

                display: none;
            }
            #menuIcon{
                display: block;
            }
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="menuIcon">Click Me</button>
    <div id="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Page</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#menuIcon").click(function(){
                $("#menu").toggle("display");
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```